# How to join hive tables based on condition of the joining column

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

We have a hive table like below:

```
num    value 

123     A 
456     B 
789     C 
101     D
```

The joining table is:

```
num       Symbols

123         ASC
456001      JEN
456002      JEN
456003      JEN
789001      CON
101         URB
```

Our expected result:

```
num   value   symbols
123    A       ASC
456    B       JEN
789    C       CON
101    D       URB
```

Currently we are joining the tables twice in order to get the results.
Like first time insert into some tmp table using the below query:

```
select
a.num,
a.value,
b.symbols
from mytable a
join mytable b on a.num = b.num;
```

This query is producing the results for `keys 123,101.`

Next, we are running another query like below:

```
select
    a.num,
    a.value,
    b.symbols
    from mytable a
    join mytable b on CONCAT(a.num,'001') = b.num;
```

This query is producing the results for `keys 456, 789`.

These two queries results are inserted into some tmp hive table and we select the final results from the tmp table.

This looks a bad design overall. but I would like to know if there is a better way to achieve this. Thanks.

Query Result

for

```
Select 
    a.num
    ,a.value
    ,b.symbols 
    from 
    (select substr(num,3) as num, value from table)a
    join 
    (select substr(num,3) as num, symbols from table) b
    on a.num = b.num

a.num   a.value b.symbols
3        A      ASC
1        D      URB
```

Answer (score 2):

OK, just one sql can implement your requirement.see below, table a is the table with value column and table b is the table with the symbols column, the SQL:

```
select
    distinct a.num,
    a.value,
    b.symbols
from
    mytable1 a
join
    mytable2 b on substr(cast(b.num as string),0,3) = cast(a.num as string)
```

Comment: This is not working either. Its giving me better results but for the key 456, it created duplicate records.

Comment: OK，I have add a DISTINCT word in SQL above , this will solved the duplicate problem. @scalauser

Comment: Well, LEFT JOIN also cause the duplicate problem, we need DISTINCT operation in the SQL.

Answer (score 0):

If datatype of num is String then you can try with Substr

```
Select 
a.num
,a.value
,b.symbols 
from a join b on 
substr(a.num,3) = substr(b.num,3)
```

Comment: This is still not giving the expected results. The keys returned for this are similar to my first query. Which is 123,101

Answer (score 0):

Can you pls try this

```
Select 
    a.num
    ,a.value
    ,b.symbols 
    from 
    (select substr(num,3) as num, value from table)a
    join 
    (select substr(num,3) as num, symbols from table) b
    on a.num = b.num
```

Comment: This has also giving me incorrect results. I have given the query result in my question as I am not able to paste it here properly

Comment: when you execute them in parts  do you see 456 instead of 456001 ?   select substr(num,3) as num, value from table

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with left semi join with above query as shown below.
    Select
    a.num,
    a.value,
    b.symbols
from
    mytable1 a
    Left semi join
    mytable2 b on substr(cast(b.num as string),0,3) = cast(a.num as string)